# How to change volume icon on Mac boot picker

Tags: startup, icon

I installed Windows and Linux on my Mac. The Linux (Fedora) partition gets an icon on the boot picker (hold <kbd>option</kbd> on power up) as shown in picture:

[image: Picture]

Just for the purpose of doing it, how can I also set an icon for the macOS and Windows partition?

Answer (score 2):

Place a 512x512 icns at the root of the partition named `.VolumeIcon.icns`. Startup Manager should pick this up and use it on that page.

Comment: Works on the macOS partition. The Windows (Bootcamp) partition doesn't work though...

Comment: @Tom Hmm, I don’t have enough experience with Boot Camp but for me my Windows is on an external disk and ‘EFI Boot’ is what shows in Startup Manager, so adding the icon to the EFI partition is what works for me. Don’t know how that translates, if at all, to Boot Camp.